# When I create a controller or class in Visual Studio 2019 it defaults to VB, even though I changed the default language to C#. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am working on an MVC website and must have selected VB instead of C# when I created the project (Side rant, why is VB even still an option?)

I changed to C# in tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset settings to C#. But that did not change anything. When I create a class or controller it still defaults to VB.

I did a bunch of configuration and set up and deleting the project and start over simply isn't an option. There should be a simple way to change it to C#, how do I do that?

Comment: What is the extension of your project file?

Comment: It's not a common enough situation that converting between the VB and C# project types has ever been supported - You may not *like* it but starting over very likely is the best way to ensure you end up with a good code base.